# Google Earth Timespan initially plots all times on load

Tags: kml, google-earth, timespan

I have an animated polygon (link below) that uses the TimeSpan parameter and ever since upgrading to Version 6 of Google Earth, it no longer animates properly with the Time slider bar.  It seems that all the polygons are loaded on the map when the kml is loaded instead of only showing the first polygon TimeSpan.  It seems that the ending slider button is set to the end of the last polygon time so that all polygons are shown.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong now in the newer version of GE?  Thanks.

[HYS2.kml](ftp://arlftp.arlhq.noaa.gov/134/HYS2.kml)

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth by default will show the entire extent of times in your KML unless you explicitly define a Time range in a *LookAt* or *Camera* element of the root-most Container which you are doing.

Your KML is correct with the gx:TimeStamp in LookAt of root-most Document. As you mention in your comment the initial time interval should not overlap the times of features in the next iteration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Document>
  <name>NOAA HYSPLIT RESULTS</name>
      <LookAt>
         ... 
         <gx:TimeStamp>
             <when>2013-05-16T13:00:00Z</when>
         </gx:TimeStamp>
         <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
      </LookAt>
...
```

The [gx:TimeStamp](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtimestamp) is supported by Google Earth 6. If you're using an older version than 6.2.2 then you should upgrade to 6.2.2 and the most current 7.x version.

If you remove the gx:TimeStamp from your LookAt then Google Earth will use whatever default behavior it implements. This behavior varies between versions so GE 7.1 and 6.2 could show a different initial view.

You can download 6.2.2 or the latest 7.1.1 version here.
http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168344

Comment: I am using version 7.1.1 and it still loads all images on load.  I found that if I take TimeStamp out of LookAt, it now works.  Why is that?

Comment: OK, I figured it out, the end time of my first time period overlaps with the beginning time of my next time period.  I just need to specify the starting time of my first time period in TimeStamp.